# Running a systemd service everyday, not at a specific time

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

Specifying `daily` as the `OnCalendar` attributes makes a service run at 00:00 everyday.

Is it possible to specify a `minimum execution interval`, like 6 hours, for a systemd timer, so that it will be rerun as soon as possible after a certain period?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `OnUnitActiveSec=6h` in the `[Timer]` section. That should make it run every 6 hours as long as the timer is active.

Comment: The `systemd.timer` man page says that `OnActiveSec` attribute `Defines a timer relative to the moment the timer unit itself is activated`. What if I set it to 1 day but I don't reboot my system after every 12 hours. It would never run.

Comment: Could you provide more details about what you're actually trying to implement?